# Node.js CLI throwing error

Tags: node.js, npm, appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

I've just installed the appcelerator CLI tools (via NPM), followed by a no-error setup. When I try to run `appc new` it throws the error `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`. Any advice to get going would be greatly appreciated!

*Note: logging via `-l` does not add any additional information, nor does the log file get created in the current working directory.*

Many thanks in advance!

**Install code**

```
$ npm install appcelerator -g
/usr/local/bin/appc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/bin/appc
/usr/local/bin/appcelerator -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/bin/appc
/usr/local/lib
└── appcelerator@4.2.2
```

**Setup code**

```
$ appc new
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.1.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016-02-01T18:38:17.223Z | ERROR  | Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of reboots and a fresh `appc setup` all is well. Must have installed badly!

Comment: Mmm, would have loved to know what it tried to split :( Could you mark your own answer as accepted so the question is closed?